# Longer stay in Prague as a tourist

Tags: schengen

I would like to apply for a Schengen visa to stay 28 days in Prague. Will that seem too long for tourism and is it likely to create problems with the visa?

I had two Schengen visas before, one of them was already for the Czech Republic.

Comment: I had two Schengen visas before one from Czech other from Italy ,bow I'm applying for Czech again on Schengen visa for tourism I want to spend I Prague 28 days so i wrote in my application 28 days , is it a problem to write such a period of time as tourist ,will it reject my application as its 28 days ?!!

Comment: As long as your total time spend there is under 90 days within 180 day period, and you didn't overstay your previous visas, there should be no problem. I assume you provided the proof of accommodation for those 28 days?

Comment: Yes George I did provide all my supporting documents too and I didn't overstayed before ,but just concerning as they will think it's too much days as tourist ,

Comment: Schengen Visa Code doesn't have any restrictions like "spending too much time at one place". And if they become concerned, they would likely contact you, and ask for clarification.

Comment: Totally agree with you

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/107362/32134) twice. Instead clarify.

Comment: I tried to rewrite the question based on your comment, is that what you wanted to ask?

Comment: What are you planning to do during these 28 days? Do you have a job you can leave for a month without trouble? If you have good answers to these questions, your application should reflect this. If you don't, it might look suspicious, although 28 days is not super-long and having used other visas previously should play in your favour.

Comment: What’s with the downvotes? This seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Yes I'm traveling as tourist to Prague ,and I have a job too I have submitted an NOC from my company too by the way I have a side trip to Bulgaria too mentioning in a cover letter

Comment: Could you please tell me more how's my application would reflect this ?!

Answer (score 0):

Your application will be granted if you *seem* to be a genuine tourist and not an illegal immigrant. Certainly Prague has more than enough tourist spots for three weeks if the visitor is interested in Czech culture, and they are also happy to accept tourists who just want to relax, *provided they are tourists and not illegal immigrants*.

- Explain how you can afford the trip, and that you will return to your job afterwards (i.e. document your income/expenditures and current job status, including the vacation).
- While four weeks might seem a lot to you, many workers in Europe get 20+ days of leave per year. Assuming a five-day workweek, that's enough for one four-week trip!